# how to load function into div? js

Tags: javascript, css

Basically I need to load dynamically  buttons into div and display them.

this is the code I have so far.
The problem is that I need to display it inside of div, because I need to show them in this way (like in the picture).
I tried with onload but apparently it doesn't work with div (`<div id="from" onload="printBtn()">)`
when i tried with iframe, the buttons shows in the wrong place.
how can i fix it?

[image: pic]

```js
var uniqfrom = ["Tel-Aviv", "Amsterdam", "New York", "London"];

function printBtn() {
  for (var i = 0; i < uniqfrom.length; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode(uniqfrom[i]);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  }
}
```

```css
body,
div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#to,
#controls,
#from {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%
}

#from {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#to {
  background-color: orange;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.sel {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="from">
    </div>
    <div id="to">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `onload` is only used for elements that load their contents asynchronously, such as `<img>` and `<script>`.

Comment: @MisterJojo The JS code is in a function, he never shows where he calls the function.

Comment: If you want to put the buttons to from tag, then you shouldn't use `document.body.appendChild(btn);` but `document.querySelector('#from').appendChild(btn);`.
So the buttons will be appended below `#from` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the DIVs that you want to put the buttons into, and append the buttons there instead of `document.body`.

```js
var uniqfrom = ["Tel-Aviv", "Amsterdam", "New York", "London"];

function printBtn() {
  let from = document.getElementById("from");
  let to = document.getElementById("to");
  for (var i = 0; i < uniqfrom.length; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode(uniqfrom[i]);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    from.appendChild(btn);
    if (i > 0) {
      btn = btn.cloneNode(true);
      to.appendChild(btn);
    }
  }
}

printBtn();
```

```css
body,
div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#to,
#controls,
#from {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%
}

#from {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#to {
  background-color: orange;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.sel {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="from">
    </div>
    <div id="to">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```